# Need help figuring out how this c++ code evaluates

Tags: c++, towers-of-hanoi

how does this code evaluate? it is giving me the correct solution to the towers of hanoi problem however I do not understand the order of evaluation.

```
void moveDisks(int n, const char* pegA, const char* pegB, const char* pegC)

{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    moveDisks(n-1, pegA, pegC, pegB);
    std::cout << "Move disk from " << pegA << " to " << pegC << std::endl;  
    moveDisks(n-1, pegB, pegA, pegC);
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the code...

Comment: Read about [recursion in general](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) and [in-order tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order_.28symmetric.29); that should help you understand how this code works.

Comment: This code blew my mind too, back when it was taught to me. The incredible power of the algorithm fitting the model, and the language fitting the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The comments are absolutely right, but in addition here's a pseudocode/callstack/output thing that might help conceptualize it:

```
moveDisks(4, "A", "B", "C");
    moveDisks(3, "A", "C", "B");
        moveDisks(2, "A", "B", "C");
            moveDisks(1, "A", "C", "B");
                Move disk from A to B
            Move disk from A to C
            moveDisks(1, "B", "A", "C");
                Move disk from B to C
        Move disk from A to B
        moveDisks(2, "C", "A", "B");
            moveDisks(1, "C", "B", "A");
                Move disk from C to A
            Move disk from C to B
            moveDisks(1, "A", "C", "B");
                Move disk from A to B
    Move disk from A to C
    moveDisks(3, "B", "A", "C");
        moveDisks(2, "B", "C", "A");
            moveDisks(1, "B", "A", "C");
                Move disk from B to C
            Move disk from B to A
            moveDisks(1, "C", "B", "A");
                Move disk from C to A
        Move disk from B to C
        moveDisks(2, "A", "B", "C");
            moveDisks(1, "A", "C", "B");
                Move disk from A to B
            Move disk from A to C
            moveDisks(1, "B", "A", "C");
                Move disk from B to C
```

You'll see diagrams like this a lot if you go read about recursion or start using a debugger like the comments suggest (and you should!).